# How can I send Notification to another user in Django

Tags: django, django-models, notifications, django-signals

When I create a task and assign it to another user, the assigned user will get a notification that someone added you to a task. The assigned user can approve/declined the task. If the invitation is accepted the task will visible to the user otherwise invitation declined notification will be returned to the author.

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_author')
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='assigned_to')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=264, verbose_name="Title ", unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Description ")
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='blog_images', verbose_name="Image", blank=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish_date', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Views.py

```
class CreateProject(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'ProjectApp/create_project.html'
    fields = ('assigned_to', 'title', 'description',)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        project = form.save(commit=False)
        project.author = self.request.user
        project.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ProjectApp:dashboard'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a status field to track project status. For example:

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=1) # status of the request: pending, denied, accepted
```

The assigned person can view a list of the project assigned to him in 'pending' status. Once accepted the request, you can update the status to 'accepted'.

Or create a new class in case you like to try to assign to more than one person before someone accepted the job

```
class ProjectRequest(models.Model)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=False)
    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1) # status of the request: pending, denied, accepted
```

The assigned person can view a list of the requests and take action. Once accepted the request, you can update the status in ProjectRequest and assigned_to in the project to this person.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of a notification? Where want to store it? The fastest way is to add some status field inside project, that can have states like 'invited, accepted, rejected', and then if it is invited, display to user and add option to accept/reject.

In that case relation between assigned_to and status field will simulate a notification that you can display somewhere, if want more complex create a separate model for notification to store how many times someone has been invited and accepted/rejected.

If want to notify user via mail/sms/device push that can check for some 3rd part libraries that can implement.